# Get Rigid Transformation for image alignment (No scaling)

Tags: c++, opencv, alignment, registration, affinetransform

I am trying to create a seamless mosaic using successive frames. I am using the estimate rigid transform function of the opencv. However the transformation matrix doesn't provide a full rigid transformation. It rather provides a similarity transformation with uniform scaling (in case the last parameter is false). How can I remove the scaling factor from the 2x3 transformation matrix? Is it possible to remove it after the calculation of the matrix?Or a new approach should be followed taking into account only rotation and translation?

Answer (score 0):

[You can easily extract the scale from this matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13150/extracting-rotation-scale-values-from-2d-transformation-matrix) and then compensate :  multiply by the invert scaling your initial matrix to have a final matrix that keep only the rotation.

Comment: consider posting the relevant part of the linked answer here.

Comment: Thank very much but it seems that if I remove the scaling, there is a drift in translation. I think the best work around is to implement an algorithm to find the rigid transformation myself (e.g. iterative closest point). and not use opencv's estimateRigidTransform()

Comment: Hi. Did you solve the problem eventually?